# Dativ oder Akkusativ? Mit und ohne "an"

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

Ich weiß manchmal nicht so recht, ob es ein Dativ oder Akkusativ sein sollte, wie das folgende Beispiel zeigt:

> - Ich habe die Gebühren an das Amt entrichtet.
>
> oder
>
> - Ich habe die Gebühren dem Amt entrichtet.

Der Dativ beantwortet ja die Frage „Wem?“ und wird auch mit der Präposition *an* gebildet, wenn es um eine statische Ortsangabe geht.

Der Akkusativ beantwortet die Frage „Wen oder was?“, doch er lässt sich ebenfalls mit *an* bilden, wenn es sich um die Angabe einer dynamischen Richtung handelt (ich → Amt).

Welche Version ist richtig und wieso?

Answer (score 2):

Zunächst eine Vorbemerkung: Von besonderer Wichtigkeit ist bei solchen Sätzen, ob eine **Präposition** im Spiel ist oder nicht. Damit haben anscheinend viele Nicht-Muttersprachler Schwierigkeiten. Häufig sieht man hier Fragen wie z.B. "Warum ist in diesem Satz ein Akkusativ, ich habe gelernt, dass dieses Verb einen Dativ verlangt", wobei der Fragesteller übersehen hat, dass vor dem Akkusativ eine Präposition steht und es sich folglich nicht um ein reguläres Akkusativobjekt, sondern um ein Präpositionalobjekt (oder eine adverbiale Bestimmung) handelt.

Nun zum vorliegenden Satz. Das Verb *entrichten* ist transitiv, es verlangt also ein Akkusativobjekt. Das Akkusativobjekt ist hier *die Gebühren*.

Jetzt mag man fragen: Was ist mit *an das Amt*? *das Amt* ist offensichtlich Akkusativ (da *das Amt* nicht Subjekt ist, kann es nicht Nominativ sein, also bleibt nur Akkusativ). Ist das also ein Akkusativobjekt?

Die klare Antwort: **Nein!** Es ist ein **Präpositionalobjekt**. Bei einem Präpositionalobjekt richtet sich der Fall vorrangig nach der Präposition. *An* erlaubt sowohl Akkusativ als auch Dativ. Da wir es hier mit einer gerichteten Handlung zu tun haben, ist hier der Akkusativ richtig.

Wir halten also fest:

> Ich habe die Gebühren an das Amt entrichtet

ist korrekt.

Was ist jetzt mit:

> Ich habe dem Amt die Gebühren entrichtet.

(Im Deutschen steht das Dativobjekt üblicherweise vor dem Akkusativobjekt)

Im Fall des Verbs *entrichten* ist ein Dativobjekt ungebräuchlich. Daher klingt dieser Satz zumindest schief und der Satz mit *an* + Akkusativ ist vorzuziehen. Wäre das Verb z.B. *geben*, wäre der Dativ vollkommen in Ordnung.

Comment: Danke sehr. Wo könnte ich nachschlagen, wie bestimmte Verben am Besten zu gebrauchen sind? Z.B. "entrichten"= ungebräuchlich mit Dativobjekt.

Answer (score 2):

Das Akkusativobjekt ist in beiden Fällen *die Gebühren*. Beide Sätze sind richtig, beschreiben aber etwas anderes.

> Ich habe die Gebühren an das Amt entrichtet.

Bei *an das Amt* handelt es sich um ein *Präpositionalobjekt*. Die Präposition *an* kann mit Dativ oder Akkusativ stehen. Mit Akkusativ handelt es sich um eine Richtung, die des Geldflusses.

> Ich habe die Gebühren dem Amt entrichtet.

Bei *dem Amt* handelt es sich um ein Dativobjekt. Dieses bezeichnet beim Verb *entrichten* (wie meistens) den Empfänger einer Sache, die des Geldes.

Answer (score 0):

Die [Antwort von RHa](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/46667/1487) ist vollkommen richtig, vor allem was die häufige Verwechslung von Präpositionalobjekten mit Akkusativ- oder Dativobjekten betrifft.

Ich möchte nur etwas zu dem Satz mit dem Dativobjekt ergänzen:

Der Dativ kann mehrere verschiedene Funktionen innehaben. In dem Satz

> Ich habe die Gebühren dem Amt entrichtet.

ist die Form des Dativs, in dem die Nominalgruppe *»dem Amt«* steht, ein *Dativus commodi*. Dabei gibt der Dativ an, wer der Nutznießer der Handlung ist.

---

Damit bedeuten die beiden Sätze folgendes:

1. > Ich habe die Gebühren an das Amt entrichtet.

   Ich habe Gebühren entrichtet, und ich habe das so gemacht, dass sich die Gebühren zum Amt hin bewegt haben.
   (Wohin? → Präpositionalobjekt)
2. > Ich habe die Gebühren dem Amt entrichtet.

   Ich habe Gebühren entrichtet, und ich habe das so gemacht, dass das Amt einen Nutzen davon hat.
   (Wem nützt das? → Dativus commodi)